# Mule flow adding weird characters to beginning of file

Tags: encoding, utf-8, mule

I'm simply moving files, but for some reason they are appending weird characters to the front of the file.
Before:

(Encoded with UTF-8)

```
testCol1,testCol2,testCol3
```

After: (Encoded with ANSI)

```
¬í ur [B¬óøTà  xp  žÌtestCol1,testCol2,testCol3
```

Things I've tried:

Explicitly setting the encoding to utf-8.

Explicitly setting the encoding to ANSI.

Using a Object to Byte Array with encoding set to utf-8.

Using a Object to String with encoding set to utf-8.

Here is my flow and relevant connectors:

```
<sftp:connector name="Sftp" maxConnectionPoolSize="3" doc:name="SFTP"/>
<file:connector name="FileConnector" autoDelete="true" streaming="false" validateConnections="true" doc:name="FileConnector"/>

<flow name="SftpOutBound" initialState="stopped">
    <file:inbound-endpoint
        path="${ftp.base}/${id}/export"
        pollingFrequency="${polling.frequency.millis}"
        responseTimeout="${standard.response.timeout.millis}"
        fileAge="${standard.fileage.delay.millis}"
        connector-ref="deletingFileConnector"
        doc:name="OutBound">
        <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="${out.filter}" />
    </file:inbound-endpoint>
    <object-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="Object to Byte Array" />

    <all doc:name="all">
        <file:outbound-endpoint
            path="${archive.out}/${id}"
            outputPattern="#[header:INBOUND:originalFileName]_#[function:datestamp:${standard.date.format}]_#[function:systime]"
            responseTimeout="${standard.response.timeout.millis}"
            connector-ref="deletingFileConnector"
            doc:name="Archive" />
        <logger
            level="WARN"
            message="Uploaded file from ${ftp.base}/${id}/export/#[header:INBOUND:originalFileName]"
            doc:name="Logger"/>
        <sftp:outbound-endpoint
            connector-ref="Sftp"
            host="${host}"
            port="${port}"
            path="${in.path}"
            user="${user}"
            identityFile="${configFullPath}/${identity.file}"
            passphrase="${passphrase}"
            responseTimeout="${standard.response.timeout.millis}"
            keepFileOnError="true"
            duplicateHandling="overwrite"
            exchange-pattern="one-way"
            outputPattern="#[header:INBOUND:originalFileName]"
            doc:name="SFTP"/>
    </all>
</flow>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems to be an issue with Mule 3.5.0, when I upgraded to 3.6.1 the issue went away. Still not sure what was causing it, but the version change solved it.

Answer (score 0):

The payload result from file:inbound-endpoint is of type InputStream. Why don't you leave as is (byte[]) to be saved by the file and sftp outbound end-points?

If you have to convert it into a string, then I suggest using `<byte-array-to-string-transformer />` after you read it instead of `<object-to-byte-array-transformer />`

Comment: I tried not doing anything with it, and let the endpoints handle it, and it still has the issue. That was what I had originally, and then I tried all the things I listed in my post.